# Proguard: Keep annotation of specific method

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, bukkit

Have have this class in my Minecraft Bukkit plugin:

```
public class AsyncPlayerChatListener implements Listener
{
    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGH)
    public void onEvent(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event)
    {
    }
}
```

And I want to keep the method along with its annotation. This is my current proguard configuration:

```
-keep class * extends org.bukkit.event.Listener {
    @org.bukkit.event.EventHandler <methods>;
}
```

ProGuard currently keeps the method and removes the annotation. How can I specify to keep all EventHandler annotations in classes implementing Listener (or all EventHandler annotation anywhere, would be fine too)?

I know

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

exists, but I guess this would make ProGuard keep any annotation anywhere.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want ProGuard to "keep any annotation anywhere"?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was unforunately unable to test this, but this may help(?):

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.bukkit.event.Listener {
    @org.bukkit.event.EventHandler public *;
}
```